# TypeOrmModule Unable to connect to the database with Nest.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

[Error IMAGE Unable to connect to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UQQL.png)

Hello, I am trying to run the following github project on my computer, https://github.com/MarcinMiler/airbnb-clone.

Here are the steps that I did that led to this problem:

1. git clone https://github.com/MarcinMiler/airbnb-clone.
2. cd server
3. enter "yarn" in the terminal. This is error results: event-stream-3.3.6.tgz not found in Yarnpkg
4. Add to server/package.json. Solution below is from https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/12077

   ,
   "resolutions": {
     "**/event-stream": "^4.0.1"
   }
5. Enter "yarn start" in the terminal.

Comment: Do you have a local instance of Postgres running (assuming Postgres based off the port)

Comment: hello, no how do I run a local instance of Postgres? Thank you very much!